# How to resolve the error while installing pear library?

Tags: php, redhat, pear

When trying to install the PEAR library, getting the following error. How to resolve this error?

```
$ ./pear install XML_Parser
```

> No releases available for package "pear.php.net/XML_Parser"
>   install failed

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: Yes, we can manuall download the XML_Parser package and then run the below command. `pear install path_to_XML_Parser`, Give the full path in path_to_XML_Parser place.